# Using reflection in method of spring service

Tags: java, spring, reflection, autowired

I have registered a service in my spring application. I have some methods with almost same nomenclature. So I am using reflection for invoking them to avoid using if else. Below is the similar scenario.

```
@Service
public class MyService {
  public List<String> getEmployee(String type) {
    Class myServiceClass = Class.forName("MyService");
    Class partypes[] = new Class[1];
    partypes[0] = String.class;
    Method meth = myServiceClass.getDeclaredMethod("getEmpBy"+type, partypes);
    Object arglist[] = new Object[1];
    arglist[0] = type;
  meth.invoke(this, arglist);
  }
}
```

Now I have methods with nomenclature as **getEmpByName, getEmpByAddress, getEmpByQualification**. To avoid if else I want to use reflection but the above code is giving not able to load **MyService** at runtime.

Comment: Class.forName expects the fully qualified name of a class. I can only hope that your class is in a package. And anyway, why load by name since you can access the class directly: `MyService.class`. But anyway, I agree with Ghostcat: do not use reflection. It makes your code slow, hard to read, not refactorable. BTW, your code doesn't make sense, since all it allows to do is to call getEmpByName("Name"), which doesn't make sense. If you has not used reflection, you would probably not have introduced  such a bug. Just remove that method, and call getEmpByName() directly.

Comment: Rename it `getEmployeesByName() while you're at it. And rename your class EmployeeService.

Comment: @GhostCat I am getting `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MyService` at 
`Class myServiceClass = Class.forName("MyService");` location

Answer (score 2):

TLDR
This design is terrible.
Use an interface instead of reflection.

More Info
You are using Spring.
Spring is happy to inject dependencies into your controllers.
Spring is almost certainly guaranteed to do a better job injecting your dependencies than you are at performing reflection.
The calling interface of your service is fixed
(notice that you hard-coded both the parameter types and the parameter order)
which, interestingly enough, is the same as with an interface.